# TableView Rotation resizes subviews

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, orientation

My app supports both portrait and landscape mode. I have a **TableViewController** that has some issues when i rotate from portrait mode to landscape mode. I want subviews of TableView not to change neither orientation nor size. But i cannot find the way. I tried from storyboard to uncheck Autoresize subviews but it did not work. **My TableView is into a TabBarController**. It is strange, that in another ViewController i have a similar TableView with exactly the same attributes that works fine. So i added some pics with the problem and with what i want.

The only code that handles TableView orientation changes is in viewDidLoadMethod the below:

```
    self.tableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

The first image is from Portrait mode

[image: Portrait Mode]

The second from troublesome Landscape mode

[image: Landscape mode]

And the third from the right TableViewController and the result that i want

[image: Expected Result]

Any advice would be helpful.

Comment: Check this **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18213376/working-with-autolayout-in-portrait-and-landscape**

Comment: @KumarKl thanks but i cannot use AutoLayout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in size inspector. I had to keep autoresizing of ImageView only TopLeft.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is setting a constraint on your imageView and force the width and height to stay fixed.