# XCode Landscape mode using Storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, adaptive-design

My current screen, portrait mode, 3 objects standing vertically is as per attachment. But to change landscape mode, all three objects got wrong. Please help me how to do for landscape mode as well.

[image]

What I expect to see is 3 object standing horizontally as per attachment.

[image]

Comment: whats going wrong???post that

Comment: Please describe what you expected to see, and what you got instead. Are you using Autolayout?

Comment: What I expect to see is 3 object standing horizontally.  @Bhavin

Comment: @fbitterlich What I expect to see is 3 object standing horizontally.

Comment: Yap, used autolayout @Bhavin

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the [size classes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/EnablingAdaptiveSizeDesign.html) feature of Autolayout.

In the Compact Height size class, uninstall the normal constraints of the three "objects" (custom views?) that anchor them vertically to each other, and add new ones that attach them side by side.

Comment: Can you pose complete example?

Comment: I can't suggest a solution if you're not saying what exactly you did so far. More details please.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this link. it will be helpfull for you.

[Evenly space multiple views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13075415/evenly-space-multiple-views-within-a-container-view)

[IOS layout for portrait and landscape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18595561/alternative-ios-layouts-for-portrait-and-landscape-using-just-one-xib-file)

[Autolayout in potrait and landscape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18213376/working-with-autolayout-in-portrait-and-landscape)