# How to set subviews with AutoLayout in UIScrollView programmatically?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiscrollview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I am creating app with UiScrollview and UIPagectontrol using Autolayout Programmatically, for

I have Created  *TKScroller* as subclass of UIView, I am init it using Some Mode and Array.

TKScroller.m

```
-(void)setData{

[self layoutIfNeeded];
CGRect mainFrame=self.frame;


[self layoutIfNeeded];
CGRect mainFrame=self.frame;
UIView *lastview;
NSMutableArray* manualConstraints = [NSMutableArray array];

for (int i=0; i<arrayData.count ; i++)
{
    CGRect frame;
    frame.origin.x = scrollView.frame.size.width * i;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    frame.size = scrollView.frame.size;

    UIView *subview = [UIView new];

    subview.backgroundColor = [self getRandomColor];
    [scrollView addSubview:subview];

    if (i==0)
    {

        NSLayoutConstraint* b1_top = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:subview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:scrollView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1 constant:5];
        [manualConstraints addObject:b1_top];

        NSLayoutConstraint* b1_left = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:subview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:scrollView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1 constant:5];
        [manualConstraints addObject:b1_left];

        NSLayoutConstraint* b1_right = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:subview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:scrollView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1 constant:-5];
        [manualConstraints addObject:b1_right];
        NSLayoutConstraint* b1_bottom = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:subview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:scrollView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1 constant:-10];
        [manualConstraints addObject:b1_bottom];

        [subview layoutIfNeeded];
        [scrollView addConstraints:manualConstraints];
        lastview=subview;
    }
    else{

        NSLayoutConstraint* b1_top = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:subview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:scrollView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1 constant:5];
        [manualConstraints addObject:b1_top];

        NSLayoutConstraint* b1_left = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:subview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:lastview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1 constant:5];
        [manualConstraints addObject:b1_left];

        NSLayoutConstraint* b1_right = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:subview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:scrollView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1 constant:-5];
        [manualConstraints addObject:b1_right];
        NSLayoutConstraint* b1_bottom = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:subview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:scrollView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1 constant:-10];
        [manualConstraints addObject:b1_bottom];

        [subview layoutIfNeeded];
        [scrollView addConstraints:manualConstraints];
        lastview=subview;

    }
}

scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width * arrayData.count, mainFrame.size.height/2);

self.pageControl.currentPage = 0;
self.pageControl.numberOfPages = arrayData.count;

 pageControlBeingUsed = NO;
}

-(UIColor *)getRandomColor{
    int r = arc4random() % 255;
    int g = arc4random() % 255;
    int b = arc4random() % 255;
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:(r/255.0) green:(g/255.0) blue:(b/255.0) alpha:1.0];
}
```

Right now i am getting any subviews,

but if i change orientation it will give incorrect result,  So how can i give `NSLayoutConstraint` for subviews of scrollview ?

**EDIT**

After adding `NSLayoutConstraint` subviews are not shown. I am just missing some constraint , please correct me in setting constraints dynamically.

My **[Source Code is here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0AGzQqxBZ9Cb0tUeEYtWmFuNXM/edit?usp=sharing)** , Please Help Me.
Thank you. And Sorry for bad grammar.

Comment: What do you mean by "incorrect result" ?

Comment: @AncAinu:pageControl goes out of view.

Comment: First of all, if you do `AutoLayout` programmatically, I advice you to [use this great Framework](https://github.com/iMartinKiss/KeepLayout) it will make your life so much easier and your code so much readable ;)

Comment: @AncAinu: Thanks for your suggestion, i dont want to use some other classes for this. plese can you help with my current implement, i'm just missing somethong little.

Comment: Do you see any information show up in the debug console when rotating the device? E.g. Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints. Usually the debug console will give you some hint as to why the views are not being displayed correctly. Also, you should be setting **translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO** on the subviews.

Comment: @Jonathan: yes i have set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=NO` and in console i am not able to get subview frame , i also have set `layoutIfNeeded` for frame but till it show so many warnings in console, look at my sourse code .

Comment: @Jonathan: Look my  NSLayoutConstraint for subviews in loop, i think i'm doing some silly mistake.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Here is a SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17097862/1597744) has explained how to do this with auto layout, he has explain perfectly , In here there is vertically textfields are there But in your case it is you have to set Horizontal views constraints.

**Alternative**

Rather that setting constraints you can set just frame of the subview and set it in Scrollview, And based on orientation you can change frames of the scrolview's subviews.

Your setData Method like,

```
-(void)setData{

    [self layoutIfNeeded];
    CGRect mainFrame=scrollView.frame;
    CGRect frame;
    for (int i=0; i<arrayData.count ; i++)
    {
        CGRect frame;
        frame.origin.x = scrollView.frame.size.width * i;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        frame.size = scrollView.frame.size;

        frame.origin=CGPointMake(0, 0);
        UIView *subview = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
        subview.backgroundColor = [self getRandomColor];
        [scrollView addSubview:subview];
    }
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width * arrayData.count, mainFrame.size.height/2);
}
```

Now you using NSNotificationCenter you can get notify when device orientation chaged, so in this selector method of it call your `setData` method,

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(setData)
                                                 name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
                                               object:nil];
```

Now in you setData method you need remove all subviews because when device changes Orientation it will add new views to your scrollview, so remove all subview from Scrollview before setting its frame,

```
        [scrollView.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
```

Make sure you are removing observer from your class like,

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replay, but in which method i need to write `NSNotificationCenter` observer ?

Comment: As you say it is custom class so right it in `init` method of it, have you implemented that method??

Comment: yes i had write `-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame array:(NSMutableArray *)array mode:(ScrollerMode)mode` method,

Comment: and Make sure you are remove this observer.

Comment: it would very thank full if you write code for that,

Answer (score 10):

In my experience with `AutoLayout` (that I use programmatically too). You should not add views directly to your `UIScrollView`.

You should do one `UIView` **and only one**, that you add as subview of your `UIScrollView`.

Once this is done, you can add all of your subviews to this `UIView`.

Everything is explained in detail here : [Apple iOS Technical Note TN2154](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html)

Comment: Yes I'm doing in this way i have `UIView > UIScrollview` and in scrollview also i'm adding one view, and in reference link has single view, i have to add multiple views into uiscrollview.

Comment: It's not what I read in your code, you do `[scrollView addSubview:subview];` in a `for` statement, so you add many views to your `UIScrollView`

Comment: in refer link they have used `NSLayoutConstraint` with **constraintsWithVisualFormat** , i am not able to do in my case, so i have used other NSLayoutConstraint way.

Comment: i have to add views in uiscrollview because i want funcationality like `iPhone` Photos app, but with pagecontrol.. SO tell me how can i achieve gallery + pagecontrol functionality without adding subviews to scrollview.

Comment: Maybe you can read carefully my answer... I explain you need to do `UIScrollView > UIView > UIView[](your photos)`.
And if I were you, I would do a `UICollectionView`with horizontal scroll and paging enabled, it should do what you want in a simpler way ;) (But I never tried to have an horizontal `UICollectionView` I admit)

Comment: Thanks for replay, and soryy because still i'm not getting what you say with `UIScrollView > UIView > UIView[](your photos)` can you give some refer link for that? or example or some code?\

Comment: And i also **don't** have much knowledge about `UICollectionView`, if it is possible with my current implementation `UIScrollview + UIPagecontrol + AutolayOut`?

Comment: `UICollectionView` is like `UITableVIew` but it does cells (square ones) so to display photos it's the best way I think.
For the solution I give you, it's in the link I gave. But it's the *mixed approach*. It's not pure AutoLayout, but since you say you can't do the other approach, it's the best way to achieve your goal.

Comment: is it done with NSConstraint Programatically ? I need autolayout programatically, and i am creating this not only for Photos, it is also used for other purpose also, so i guess i am not go with collectionView. i havent experience with collectionView.

Comment: You just use `autoresizing mask`for the intermediate `UIView` and you use AutoLayout like you want for your Photos etc. inside.

Comment: Thnks again but in my case it will not so useful, i need to do with `NSLayoutConstraint` only, i know it is possible , but dont know how to set that in loop.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48072/discussion-between-anc-ainu-and-user203108)

Comment: Thank you, this technical note explains it. I used approach 1 and it works fine!

Answer (score 5):

I know that the problem has been solved. and i hope that this solution my help for some people so i am posting it.

Below code is for adding the scrollview to the uiviewcontroller

```
  self.scrollView = UIScrollView()
    self.scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    self.scrollView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    self.scrollView.scrollEnabled=true
    self.scrollView.pagingEnabled = true
    self.view.addSubview(self.scrollView)

    self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[scrollView]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: ["scrollView":self.scrollView]))

    self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[scrollView]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: ["scrollView":self.scrollView]))
```

After added the scrollview and add the subviews/images like this(this is an example for images showing in full size of scrollview like in photos app )

```
var prev:UIImgeView?

        for var index = 0; index < self.images.count; ++index {
            var iview = UIImgeView()
            iview.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
            self.scrollView.addSubview(iview)
            var image = self.images.objectAtIndex(index) as UIImage
            iview.image = image
            if (index == 0){
                self.scrollView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[iview(==scrollView)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: ["iview":iview,"scrollView":self.scrollView]))
                prev = iview

            }
            else{
                self.scrollView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:[prev][iview(==prev)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: ["iview":iview,"prev":prev!]))
                prev = iview
            }
            self.scrollView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[iview(==scrollView)]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: ["iview":iview,"scrollView":self.scrollView]))

            if (index == self.images.count-1){
                self.scrollView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:[prev]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: ["prev":prev!]))

            }

        }
```

Comment: Is this layout for views with a horizontal or vertical layout?

Answer (score 0):

If you want your TKScroller fixed to the center and support orientation changes, you can simply put the following code in your init

```
self.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```

and you may need to check all your subview's of TKScroller.  If you don't like autosize , you can set (one of the three)

```
self.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
self.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
self.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
```

Comment: That's only good for backwards compatibility sake (and using `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO`), but I don't think it's what OP wants.