# UISlider causing horizontal scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uilabel, uislider

I have a simple screen, with a slider and a label positioned next to each other horizontally. I have embedded these inside a `UIScrollView` (I set this to fill the screen and used 'Add missing constraints'), because I will need vertical scrolling later down the line. I don't however, want horizontal scrolling. I have seen numerous posts on here and other sources about people wanting to disable horizontal scrolling, however I'm not sure that's what I want to do, I think I need to restrict the `UISlider` from causing the horizontal scrolling; I think it is trying to take up more width than the screen. I have added what I think are the necessary horizontal constraints:

- Leading space to container for the `UISlider`
- Horizontal spacing to the `UILabel`, and
- Trailing space to container for the `UILabel`

But this still causes horizontal scrolling, and the `UISlider`'s are the cause, they are taking up more room than I want, as seen below:

[image: Constraints on the UISlider and UILabel]

[image: What it looks like in the simulator]

I have tried disabling horizontal scrolling in the code using a few techniques, one being:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView.contentOffset.x>0 {
        scrollView.contentOffset.x = 0
    }
}
```

but this does not seem to stop the horizontal scrolling.

Can anyone offer any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show what you've already tried, and screen shots of the results you're getting.

Comment: Sure, just preparing a few screenshots now. Sorry, I should've put these up in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is to **never** use *Add missing constraints*.  It never does what you really want.

Here's the problem.  You are laying out your UI on a `ViewController` in the Storyboard that is square.  Apple did this to remind you that you need to be flexible in your design, but it doesn't match the size of *any* device.  When you *Add missing constraints*, it uses the absolute dimensions of that square to create the constraints which are certainly wrong.

In your specific case, it is giving the slider a width that is too wide, which is why the slider goes off the right side of your screen.

Here's the trick about scroll views.  If the contents inside of a scroll view are wider than the scroll view itself, then that content will scroll.  The same applies vertically:  if the contents inside of a scroll view are taller than the scroll view, then the contents will scroll.

In order to design this to work on all phones, you need to make sure that the contents of the scroll view are laid out correctly for each phone size.  Which certainly means you don't want to use specific widths for both the label and the slider because you'll end up with the wrong width for some device, if not all of them.

The best way to do this is to:

1. Drag out the scroll view and add it to your ViewController.  Add constraints to make sure it is properly sized on all phones, such as attaching it on all sides to its superview with a fixed distance.
2. Drag out a new `UIView` and drop it on the scroll view.  Drag its edges until it exactly matches the size of the scroll view.  This will be your content view.  Pin all four edges of this content view to the scroll view with offsets of `0`.
3. Here's a tricky bit.  Even though you've pinned the content view to the scroll view, its size of free to grow because that is what allows it to be bigger than the scroll view itself and allow there to be content to scroll over.  To keep your scroll view from scrolling horizontally, you need to make sure the content view has the same width as the scroll view on all devices.  To do that, find the scroll view and the content view in the *Document Outline* to the left of the Storyboard.  <kbd>Control</kbd>-drag from the content view to the scroll view and select *Equal Widths* from the pop-up.

   [image: Control-drag in Document Outline view]
4. You still haven't told your content view how tall it should be.  For now, give it an explicit height constraint of `1000`.  That will be enough to scroll.
5. Now, add your label and slider to the content view.  In addition to constraining them to each other and to the edges of the content view, you will need to give your label a width constraint.  Then *Auto Layout* will have all of the information it needs to compute the width of your slider.  *Auto Layout* knows how wide the content view is (which will be different on different devices), it knows how wide your label is, and how far everything is from everything else, so it will just stretch the slider to fill in the rest.

If you do all of this, you will have a UI that is properly sized for all devices in all orientations that scrolls vertically.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer, I understand the problem a lot better. One question though - giving the content view and explicit height, is this not bad? Won't this force the screen to be scrollable even if there's not enough content to warrant vertical scrolling ability?

Comment: @TophatGordon, you have to do something to make sure the content view height is specified.  In your final solution, instead of giving it an explicit height, you should make sure the topmost subview of the content view is constrained to the top of the content view, with each subview constrained to its nearest neighbor and the bottommost subview constrained to the bottom of the content view.  If you do that and fully specify the height of each subview, then Auto Layout will be able to calculate the height of the content view for you.

Comment: Ahhh I see, - the 1000 (or whatever height) is just temporary until the views are all on the screen, this makes much more sense now. Got it working perfectly after adding all of my views onto the content view, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Just embed all view in your `UIScrollView` in a `UIView`, give it the required constraints then the slider and label will stay.

That worked for me just now.

Answer (score 0):

UIScrollView is special when you want use AutoLayout with it, subviews can not be added directly, it needs a container view to constraint the contentSize of UIScrollView, [Auto Layout Guide:Working with Scroll Views](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithScrollViews.html) explains the detail reason, and you can find many solutions to solve UIScrollView's auto layout on Google, Such as this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21934558/how-to-set-subviews-with-autolayout-in-uiscrollview-programatically).

To be honest, it's confused and complicated to understand UIScrollView's auto layout, but if you overcome this, others auto layout question is easy to resolve.