# Shrink white space within elements in a UIView for iOS 7 using Storyboards and Autolayout

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview

I don't know if I can accomplish this because I can't find any information or tutorial doing what I need to do, and maybe this just can't be accomplish at all and I am wasting my time.

What I want to do is to shrink the white space between diffenrent element inside the same **UIView** for **iOS 7** using *storyboards* and *autolayout*, so they can re-arrange themselves to fit nicely inside a 3.5 inch screen and landscape mode.

[image]

I've been working on this the last 3 days and no matter what I try to do with the constrains, I can't make it look the way I want it in landscape or 3.5 inch screen.

**This is what I want!**

[image]

Maybe some of you can give me some hint about it, or just let me know if I can even do this, because I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17089427/ios-autolayout-vertically-equal-space-to-fill-parent-view

Comment: Couldn't find that one. Thank you, I'm gonna try it at the morning.