# How to get NSLayoutConstraint programmatically between UIButtons?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uibutton, nslayoutconstraint

In a view I'm inserting a new UIButton, As I have been using AutoLayout, I need to get constraint of the view below which I'm going to insert button. How do I get the NSLayoutConstraint programmatically, so that I can delete the old constraint create new one afterwards. Thanx.

Edit:[image]

with ref to diagram, I need to insert B3 between B1 and B2, So I need to delete the already set fixed space constraint between B1 and B2, and I need to connect B3 bottom to B2's top and B3's top to B1's bottom.

Comment: Are you certain you need to delete the constraint? Can you show a diagram/code of what the constraints are.

Comment: Cool, OK yeah you'll need to delete. OK, gimme a sec... actually, can't answer now. Take a look on the github project linked from here though http://www.oliverfoggin.com/an-auto-layout-experiment/ I do this a lot.

Comment: okay I'll check thank you...

Comment: I don't get what you need: all the constraints to draw this ? Or something else ?

Comment: I believe the question is: *How do I get the NSLayoutConstraint programmatically, so that I can delete the old constraint create new one afterwards.*, which, in other words, means: *How can I get a hold of the old constraint*.

Answer (score 2):

> I need to delete the already set fixed space constraint between B1 and B2

## Finding a constraint programmatically

You can either search for `B1` in the view constraints, or keep a reference to the `NSLayoutConstraint` when you created it. Searching the constraints for `B1` is probably less efficient: all the relationship constraints (view to another view) are part of the enclosing `superview`. Assuming you have a handle to `B1`, you can list all `B1` constraints in its superview like so:

```
// Searching all relationship constraints involving b1
for item in self.view.constraints() {
    if let constraint = item as? NSLayoutConstraint {
        if let button = constraint.firstItem as? UIButton {
            if button == b1 {
                println("firstItem found: \(constraint)")
            }
        }
        if let button = constraint.secondItem as? UIButton {
            if button == b1 {
                println("secondItem found: \(constraint)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## Remembering a constraint

By far, the cleaner approach is to keep a reference to the `NSLayoutConstraint` you want to later modify or delete. To do this in a Storyboard, create the constraints you need.

[image]

Then control-drag a reference directly into your source file to manipulate them later.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can turning off the default constraints applied to views as below. apply below code while you first Created Button programmatic.

```
B1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
B2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
B3.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
```

After adding all button in to your View using `AddSubView` set your Constrain again as par your need for example below.

```
// Center the middle one vertically
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:B2 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier:1.0 constant:0]];
```

hope it's help you i found best answer in Stack Overflew from
[Evenly space multiple views within a container view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13075415/evenly-space-multiple-views-within-a-container-view)
 Al the very best.

Comment: Thanks for your answer I'll check and let u know.

Comment: Tried your code.. new button is placed in place of second item (in ur case self.view) not by moving down the second button.

Comment: avoid my example just turning of default constraints using translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints and apply your logic only

Comment: not sure how to bring down all subviews below once new button is added using constraints