# Equally distribute spacing using Auto Layout visual format string

Tags: cocoa-touch, user-interface, uiview, nslayoutconstraint, autolayout

Is it possible to equally distribute left and right space for `b` in `@"|-[a(5)]-[b(8)]-[c(5)]-|"` using visual format strings?

Comment: VERY GOOD SO article related to this question  [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13075415/evenly-space-multiple-views-within-a-container-view/25898949#25898949)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No.

However, you can do it with visual format and a manual constraint creation. Change your VFL string to:

```
@"|-[a(5)]->=0-[b(8)]->=0-[c(5)]-|"
```

This says that you're not too concerned about the actual size of the spaces between a and b, and b and c.

Now, create a constraint pinning the center of b to the center of the superview using `constraintWithItem:...` (I'm typing this on a phone so forgive me for not spelling out the whole method).

This, coupled with your flexible spacing, will give even spaces to the left and right of b.

Comment: How exactly did you “pin the center of b to the center of the superview”, @flohei? And isn’t it possible to use the visual format for that as well or must one use `constraintWithItem:attribute:relatedBy:toItem:attribute:multiplier:constant:`?

Answer (score 15):

Apple's [Auto Layout Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AutoLayoutbyExample/AutoLayoutbyExample.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH5-SW8) suggests using "spacer views". Here's the solution for laying out your three views with equal spacing horizontally:

```
// create views dictionary
NSMutableDictionary *viewsDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[viewsDictionary addEntriesFromDictionary:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(viewA, viewB, viewC)];

// create 4 spacer views
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    UIView *spacerView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    spacerView.hidden = YES;
    [self addSubview:spacerView];
    [viewsDictionary setObject:spacerView
                        forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"spacer%d", i + 1]];
}

// disable translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints in views for auto layout
[viewsDictionary enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) 
{
    [obj setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
}];

// add constraints
[superview addConstraints:
 [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:
  @"|[spacer1(>=0)][viewA][spacer2(==spacer1)][viewB][spacer3(==spacer1)][viewC][spacer4(==spacer1)]|"
                                         options:kNilOptions
                                         metrics:nil
                                           views:viewsDictionary]];
```

Note that `spacer1`'s width is set to be more than 0. Subsequent spacer views are set to have equal widths with `spacer1`.

Comment: Is there any reason you didn’t simply write `NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(viewA, viewB, viewC);`?

Comment: I've edited my answer to use multiple arguments in NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings. I'm using a mutable dictionary so that I can add my spacer views to it dynamically.

Comment: Oh, right. ^___^ `NSMutableDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(viewA, viewB, viewC).mutableCopy;` then.