# Resize proportionnaly between iphone 4 and 5 screens with XCode

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout

I am trying to use auto layout in x code to correctly resize my view to switch between iphone 4 and 5.

I have a similar problem as the one presented in the picture. Let's consider the UILabel at the bottom is fixed. 
I want the top UILabel to be at the middle of the space between the navigation bar and the bottom label. I don't know how to add a constraint that says "top space and bottom space must be equal". As a result, I can only fix one of the two constraints and I cannot get the expected result.

Thanks

[image: On the iPhone 5 screen, my top UILabel is not vertically centered.]

Comment: Does this answer help? It's a little more complicated situation, but I think the same principles are involved: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19327095/xcode-5-autolayout-equal-distribution-of-6-views

Comment: Thanks, I will have a lot. I put the label in a view, it works great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I do this in IB, is to embed the top label in a UIView. Give that view a standard vertical spacing constraint to the top layout guide, and another to the bottom label. Also give it a fixed width. Give the label centerX and centerY constraints to this view, and it should keep it centered in different screen sizes.

Answer (score 1):

How about adding a container view that fills up the space between the 1st label and the navigation bar, and then center the 2nd label inside the container view.

Comment: I have never used container view, so I use a simple view and put the label inside. It works great.
Thank you for your answer.