# How to adjust font size for various iPhone screen sizes in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I have an app designed for 5s with a font size of 13px. But when the same is run in iPhone6 Plus font is looking very tiny. Although position and size of the elements is adjusting accordingly to the size thanks to percentage based element position and layout.

Any idea on how to change the font according to screen size ?

Comment: What about size classes and magic of auto layout? :)
Also, looks like this question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27828038/how-do-i-handle-iphone-6s-pluss-font-size

Comment: @Oleshko I went through the question. It makes sense, but I can't change the font size with  size classes and auto layout right ? Just confirming.

Comment: You can do it in storyboard. Don't need to write conditions

Comment: could you let me know how ? Using autoShrink ? I tried it but it doesn't see to do anything. At least in simulator

Comment: I was talking about size classes. Are you using size classes in your project?

Comment: as we are targeting only portrait size iPhones we didn't have to do it yet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/113768/adaptive-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-getting-started) is an example of how you can customize font for different devices (section Adaptive Fonts almost in the end of tutorial)

**Short instruction how to do this:**

1. Select label in Interface Builder
   [image]
2. Press + button near Font and select device size, for which you want to have another font
   [image]
3. Set new font for that devices[image]

Comment: iphone 6 and 5 have same ratio so this solution does not work for me :(