# xcode8 layout equal margin from left and right

Tags: ios, xcode, constraints

[image]

I am having hard time laying out my buttons. I want them to have equal margin from left and right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an *equal distribution* problem. It is in fact extremely tedious to solve by hand! (See my explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20865342/341994) if you want to know the gory details.) That is why you should use a [UIStackView](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uistackview). It will perform equal distribution for you, by making for you, automagically, the constraints that *you* would have had to make in order to accomplish the same thing.