# How to position multiple views on the same distance

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

I have the following View:

[image]

How to make so that they all are at the same distance between each other ? Preferably to be done using autolayout (not programmatically), but any answer would be great.

Currently stucked with Tue, Wed, Fri, Sat.
Monday has a constraint `Leading space to superview`. Thursday is `centered horizontally` and Sunday has `Trailing space to superview`.

So basically need to position Tue and Wed so that distances between Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu are the same... (and same for Fri and Sat)

Comment: Have you looked at using a horizontal stack view?

Comment: thanks :) didn't know about it. but it doesn't work for ios 7, 8..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this solution(fully based on autolayout in storyBoard):
 https://github.com/Petro-Lomaka/equalButtonsWidthAutoLayout

Answer (score 1):

> How to make so that they all are at the same distance between each other ? Preferably to be done using autolayout (not programmatically)

You are describing the problem of _equal distribution.

This is *exactly* what a stack view is for — but, as you have said, stack views are a recent creation. So what if you need to do this on an earlier system, where there are no stack views? You need to do, in essence, what a stack view does — you insert *spacer views*. You can easily specify, using constraints, that these spacer views have equal widths to one another, and this, together with your other constraints, will solve the problem.

Comment: For a full explanation, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20865342/341994

Comment: oh, got it. good solution. thanks!