# Constraints to center and object between two objects

Tags: ios, autolayout, storyboard, uistackview, uilayoutguide

My design requires that a button is centered between two other objects. One of the objects is in the vertical center of the view (green). The other object is some distance from the bottom edge (green). Now the task is to center the third object (red) between the other two. I am using xcode6's new constraints and my view is in wRegular hRegular mode. This would be easy with code, but I am trying to use the storyboard to accomplish this.

[image]

Comment: for iOS9 check http://stackoverflow.com/a/33733753/1067147

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are a number of approaches:

- In iOS 9, the easiest would be to define a vertical `UIStackedView` with a `distribution` of "equal spacing" and then `addArrangedSubview` the three circular subviews
- Another option in iOS 9 would be to create two `UILayoutGuide` (which would represent the two question marks in your image), add them to the shared superview with `addLayoutGuide` and define them to be the same size as each other. The corresponding VFL might look like:

  ```
  "V:|[greenView1(==100)]-[layoutGuide1]-[redView(==50)]-[layoutGuide2(==layoutGuide1)]-[greenView2(==greenView1)]|"
  ```
- In earlier iOS versions, rather than using `UILayoutGuide`, you could just create two "space" views (`UIView` with clear background so they're not visible) then define a constraint such that their heights are identical, and then define vertical spacing constraints between the five views (the three circles and the two spacer views) with a constant of zero.

  It might look like:

  [image: IB scene]

  I've made those "spacer" views visible, to illustrate the idea, but obviously you'd set them to be transparent so you can't see them in the UI.

  This is logically equivalent to the `UILayoutGuide` approach in iOS 9, except that the `UIView` "spacer" views just carry a little more overhead than a `UILayoutGuide`. But in iOS versions before 9, this is the common approach to this problem.

Comment: You can do it with one spacer.  Pin the top of the spacer to the bottom of the upper green circle.  Pin the bottom of the spacer to the top of the lower green circle.  Pin the vertical center of the red circle to the vertical center of the spacer.

Comment: Agreed. Lots of ways of skinning the cat. I use individual spacers so that it works with more than three circles without dealing with multipliers (though you can now do that, too).

Comment: Both great solutions! I like that in the first solution the red button doesn't need to be a child of the spacer views. Thank you.

Comment: FYI, for the benefit of future readers, I've updated my answer to reflect two new approaches available in iOS 9, namely `UIStackedView` and `UILayoutGuide`.

Answer (score 1):

I've come up with easiest approach.

[image: newly added view is in blue color. and in my case label should be in center]

Just follow these steps :

1. add a view between them the two circle
2. add its trailing and leading space. (in my case zero to superview)
3. add top and bottom space from the circles.
4. now put your red circle in the recently added view
5. make it horizontally and vertically center from Alrignment Menu

[image: alignment]