# Autolayout for iphone 6 and iphone 6 plus

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, iphone-6, iphone-6-plus

I have been try a good solution for this problem... I have an app and this work perfect in iphone 4, and iphone 5, But in iphone 6 and 6 plus i don't know how made a good solution with autolayout.

the problem is: my app is a clone of a home screen, and i need that all the icons have the same position in all devices

I don't know how to let the space between the icons flexible

iphone 4 and 5

[image]

for iphone 6 should look like, but if it works for one does not work in another
[image]

Thanks

Comment: "the problem is: my app is a clone of a home screen" IIRC, Apple rejects these now.

Comment: it's a fake home with black background and  just color icons. i'm asking something different ;)

Comment: Out of curiosity: is there a reason you're not using a UICollectionView for this kind of design? It seems like a collection view in conjunction with a flow layout would be perfect.

Comment: Yes, it's a little game, and i use some views in the some positions. My doubt is possible create flexible constraints?

Comment: Since this question is more than a month old, you have probably solved it already. If not this may be worth a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13075415/evenly-space-multiple-views-within-a-container-view