# How do I place four buttons evenly with AutoLayout?

Tags: ios, autolayout

There are four circle `UIButtons` in `UIView`. Their layout should look like this:

｜－ button 1 - button 2 - button 3 - button 4 －｜

I tried some ways with AutoLayout but failed. 
Can someone give me some advice or demo about how to build this layout?

Comment: Not sure if you need to evenly space these buttons. If so, this may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13075415/evenly-space-multiple-views-within-a-container-view. There's also these tutorials: http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Firstly, set up the leading and the trailing constraints of the 1st and 4th button. Then, create `horizontal spacing` constraints in the middle between the other buttons.
2. Right-click on  a button and choose `width` and `height` in order to set fixed width and height.
3. Set `equal widths` and `equal heights` by right-clicking and dragging from a button to the other ones.

Please take a look at this GIF image:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's really helpful. However, the fourth button won't be evenly space when device screen become larger. like:|-x-x-x---x-| , In other word, horizontal spacing size is not adapt. Can I ask how to update? Thanks.

Comment: Please take a look at the GIF image in my answer.

Comment: Really appreciate for your so great help! Now the final effect will be like |-x-x----x-x-|.  can I ask how to realize the  same width of horizontal space between every two buttons?

Comment: Just tap on the button, open the Utilities inspector and choose Size Inspector. Under the "Constraints" panel you can change the `constant` of the constraint.

Comment: That's great to hear! Thanks for having accepted my answer :)