# Space evenly across a view without margins

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, autolayout

I use following function to space a dynamic number of views across a View (with autolayout):

```
-(NSArray*)spaceViews:(NSArray *)views onAxis:(UILayoutConstraintAxis)axis
{
    NSAssert([views count] > 1,@"Can only distribute 2 or more views");

    NSLayoutAttribute attributeForView;
    NSLayoutAttribute attributeToPin;

    switch (axis) {
        case UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal:
            attributeForView = NSLayoutAttributeCenterX;
            attributeToPin = NSLayoutAttributeRight;
            break;
        case UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical:
            attributeForView = NSLayoutAttributeCenterY;
            attributeToPin = NSLayoutAttributeBottom;
            break;
        default:
            return @[];
    }

    CGFloat fractionPerView = 1.0 / (CGFloat)([views count] + 1);

    NSMutableArray *constraints = [NSMutableArray array];
    [views enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIView *view, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)
    {
        CGFloat multiplier = fractionPerView * (idx + 1.0);
        [constraints addObject:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view 
                                                            attribute:attributeForView 
                                                            relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual 
                                                               toItem:self 
                                                            attribute:attributeToPin 
                                                           multiplier:multiplier 
                                                             constant:0.0]];
    }];

    [self addConstraints:constraints];
    return [constraints copy];
}
```

*(The function is from [UIView-Autolayout](https://github.com/jrturton/UIView-Autolayout))*

The problem is that it has margins. How could this method be changed in order to evenly space the views without margins?

**UPDATE**

It seems that the method is not working correctly after all, the margins on the outer items are much higher than at the rest.

As an example I changed the code for the left arm to:

```
self.leftArm = [UIView autoLayoutView];
self.leftArm.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

[self.view addSubview:self.leftArm];

[self.leftArm pinAttribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight toAttribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft ofItem:self.body withConstant:-10.0];
[self.leftArm pinAttribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop toSameAttributeOfItem:self.body withConstant:10.0];
[self.leftArm constrainToSize:CGSizeMake(20.0, 200.0)];
```

Now the robot looks like this:

[image]

Note that at the left arm the views are NOT evenly distributed, the margin on top and at the bottom are much higher. I can reproduce the same behavior horizontally and with less items.

I have successfully removed the margins by aligning the outer views with the sides of the superview and aligning the rest within the space between. But now, due to this problem, I always have bigger spaces between the outer views and the views next to them as between the rest.

Does anyone know how to correct this?

**UPDATE 2**

I have created a fork and added my function to it, I also extended the robot example so you can see what I mean.

Please [take a look](https://github.com/dkk/UIView-Autolayout).

Comment: I recognise that code :D I'm not sure what you mean by the margins comment - do you mean you want the edge views to be aligned to the edge of the superview?

Comment: @jrturton yes, and the rest of the views evenly spaced

Comment: My esteemed colleague James Frost has you covered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have extended [jrturton's UIView-Autolayout](https://github.com/jrturton/UIView-Autolayout) (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15347350/386738)) and created a [pull request](https://github.com/jrturton/UIView-Autolayout/pull/34).

It is now possible to distribute the views evenly without margins by calling the new function:

```
-(NSArray*)spaceViews:(NSArray *)views 
               onAxis:(UILayoutConstraintAxis)axis
           withMargin:(BOOL)margin
```

and setting the margin parameter to `NO`.

You can already find that version of UIView-Autolayout [here](https://github.com/dkk/UIView-Autolayout).

The brand new robot with evenly spaced views as teeth:
[image: Robot]

Answer (score 2):

It looks as though this code is from [UIView-Autolayout](https://github.com/jrturton/UIView-Autolayout). The latest version of the library has a new method which lets you stop the spacing from being added to edges:

```
-(NSArray*)spaceViews:(NSArray*)views
               onAxis:(UILayoutConstraintAxis)axis
          withSpacing:(CGFloat)spacing
     alignmentOptions:(NSLayoutFormatOptions)options
    flexibleFirstItem:(BOOL)flexibleFirstItem
  applySpacingToEdges:(BOOL)spaceEdges;
```

Just call this method instead and pass `NO` to the last argument.

Comment: Unfortunately this method has a parameter "spacing", where the distance between views is defined. (I already tried that)

Comment: You could pass 0 for spacing? If you don't want spacing between the views, what is it that the original method you posted isn't doing as you'd like?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want is possible, in that case. The spaceViews:onAxis method distributes the centers of the views evenly along the axis, letting them occupy their own intrinsic size. The methods with spacing calculate a width and forces them to occupy equal widths. If the views are different sizes, how can you make "even" spacing?

Comment: The views that I am adding are UIImageViews, they get expanded with this function (with the one I posted they had margins). But now that I think of it, I could just include them centered in another view that could get expanded.. problem solved!

Comment: my first idea was to align the first view left, the last right and distribute the rest evenly across the view-the space the 2 views occupy. But that's more difficult. And I am not sure if I can get the sizes of the first and last view without using frame

Comment: Ehhmm, if I add them in another view and they get expanded... I get margins again

Comment: @jrturton my first idea did work, but it has a bug, please see my update.