# How to center two elements with auto layout?

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints

How to center two middle squares with autolayout to preserve equal spaces between all of them?

[image: pic]

Actually, i can outlet constraints and set it with computations involving container width and so on, but maybe there is some more smart way?

Comment: Do you want to use interfacebulder or by the code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My approach, with Interfacebuidler, is using "spacer views"

Spacer views are UIView that I have set to **match widths equally**.

[image: Autolayout - vertically]

**.1.** Black frames are UIViews

**.2.** UIImageView are squares

**.3.** Set equals width beetween *spacer views*

**.4.** Set equals width beetween *squares*

**.4.** Add edge constraints beetween *spacer views* and *squares*

**.5.** Set *spacer view* to transparent

*If you need more detail to do that with Interface builder or by the code you should read this post :*

[Evenly space multiple views within a container view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13075415/evenly-space-multiple-views-within-a-container-view)

Hope this can help you ;)