# Center multiple views with varying height using autolayout

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, autolayout

This answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25898949/1364053 is suitable for my problem to some extent. What I need is there are three views in my container view.

The middle one is a scroll view. If I pin height and width of all three views and use the ratio method as described in the above link, all works fine.

But I need the middle scrollview to grow to some extent, let's say the current height of the scroll view is 30, If the device height is increased it should grow to a max of 40 but not more than that (<= constraint).

Ok..So I tried giving two constraints to the middle view. The <= constraint has higher priorty (750) than the = constraint (250).. but when the screen size is increased.. the height stays the same.  [image]

[image]

Comment: have you tried adding that constraint? just add the height limit to it and give it a higher priority than the actual proportional height constraint. That way it will be of some height but always <= your specified upper bounds.

Comment: Correct me If I understood it wrong.. I should add two height constraints.One with equal height and other with <= height.. and the <= should have more priority than the = one?

Comment: Yes, Xcode will try so satisfy all of them and in case of conflicting ones, prioritize them based on your settings. That will result in the desired behaviour.

Comment: No luck.. please check the edited question

Comment: I thought you used the "ratio method"!? Your current constraint settings don't look like that...

Comment: ratio method is there but since the views are of different height.. Some constant has to be added.. check the edited question.. I have added the image

Comment: here is good tutorial check it http://makeapppie.com/2014/07/26/the-swift-swift-tutorial-how-to-use-uiviews-with-auto-layout-programmatically/

Comment: I don't think the link addresses my problem.

Answer (score 0):

[Sample.xib](https://www.dropbox.com/s/58oz0crsxs9fho4/Sample.xib?dl=0)
The uploaded xib might help you.

[image: Constraints screenshot]