# Swift Center View Horizontal Ratio

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, constraints, nslayoutconstraint

I am creating a view within IB and and attempting to have 3 `UILabels` evenly space horizontally across the view. I came across this on SO, https://stackoverflow.com/a/30249550/4597666. I have three `UILabels`, each have the height and width constrained. Here is what the IB looks like:

[image]

I constrained each centered horizontally, and the first `UILabel` I have the multiplier `3:1`, second, `3:3`, third `3:5` like the post states.

[image][image][image]

When I run on my emulator, I don't get the result that I was expecting. It appears all three `UILabel`s are centered horizontally, and the first and third are not offset.

[image]

Is there another setting that I'm missing, or another way to properly space the views evenly?

Comment: Have you checked the first and second are definitely behind the 3rd in the centre? Or are they potentially offscreen elsewhere?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I went and checked more into it, and the ratios were actually backwards. Instead of doing 3:1 I needed 1:3. Likewise with 3:5 I needed 5:3.

Comment: Just a heads up, if you do it that way, I'm pretty sure there will be even spacing between the middle view and the outer 2 views, but this gap will not be equal to the gap between the outer views and the edges of the screen. If you want equal gaps between screen edges and all views you may need a different method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to make only one change.

Constraint you set is **3.CenterX to Superview.CenterX** all you need to do is **interchange** the value so that you constraint should look like in below image.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Alternative solution. If you want to set constraints currently you have set then change the ratio from **"3:5"** to **"5:3"** and similar for all the labels.

[image]

Result:

[image]

[image]
Hope it helps you solving your problem.