# How to use Masonry layout some views with same space?

Tags: ios, autolayout, masonry

I have some views with known width in my project, I want layout these views with same space.

I could add some "placeholder views" with same width as these empty space , but is there any other solutions?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: If you're supporting iOS9 use UIStackView. Otherwise, no.

Comment: Thanks, but our project should be supported from iOS6 to iOS9

Comment: iOS6?! Seriously. iOS9 is now out. You really shouldn't be supporting 3 versions back. I'd drop iOS 6 and 7 if I were you. The usage is so small and the benefits from dropping them are huge. 6 should have gone long ago.

Comment: T_T Drop iOS 6 or not is another question, Chinese users, strange guys.

Comment: The autolayout can help you. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13075415/evenly-space-multiple-views-within-a-container-view)