# How to set 4 UIView with same gap in one single UIView with Constraints iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, constraints

[image]

I'hv 4 `UIView`s. All of them are in a parent `UIView`. The Parent has it's fixed height constraint which is 240. But I have to minimize it to 190 for iPhone 4.

[image]

The height of the child views are fixed. Now My question is how can I set all those 4 UIView in it's parent view with same Gap so that If I just change the height of It's parents view, child view could fit automatically with same Gap in it's parent View.

Thanks a lot in advance.

**Parents View constraint :**

Leading 0
Trailing 0
Top to it's Parents X
Bottom to it's Parents Y
Height 240 (which I have to decrease in iPhone 4)

**Child View constraint :**

**Sign In with Facebook View Constraints:**
Leading 0
Trailing 0
Top 0
Vertical fixed with the second below child view(I set it with a fixed value like <= X which doesn't work)

**Sign In with Twitter View Constraints:**
Leading 0
Trailing 0
Vertical fixed with the third below child view(I set it with a fixed value like <= X which doesn't work)

**Sign In with phone View Constraints:**
Leading 0
Trailing 0
Vertical fixed with the fourth below child view(I set it with a fixed value like <= X which doesn't work)

**Sign In with email View Constraints:**
Leading 0
Trailing 0
Bottom to it's parents 0

Comment: You may use stackView; https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStackView_Class_Reference/

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion, but unfortunately my deployment target is iOS 7.0. :(

Comment: This will work for you then: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25898949/988169

Comment: btw why do you need a Top constraint for twiiter, phone and email aren't you keeping a vertical space between the current view and it's top view. Just remove them and check it

Comment: It was a mistake. I edited my post. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found an alternative way to do it. The system is, put 3 extra `UIView` in each Gap. Like this.

[image]

Now named it like this:

**1stSeperatorView

2ndSeperatorView

3rdSeperatorView**

Clear all vertical constraints of ChildViews, except top one & bottom one. Now set seperator Views constraint like the below :

**1stSeperatorView :**
Leading 0
Trailing 0
vertical with it's top 0
vertical with it's bottom 0

**2ndSeperatorView :**
Leading 0
Trailing 0
vertical with it's bottom 0

**3rdSeperatorView :**
Leading 0
Trailing 0
vertical with it's bottom 0

Now the most important thing. **Select 3 seperator view togather and set their Equal Height constrains from the Constraint Panel**. Update Frame. Change the height of the Parents view as you want. It should be working perfectly.

Thanks a lot again to all, for your time. :)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, in your case I'd use a `UIButton`, but let's discuss the solution...

Set in your storyboard the desired spacing between views. Try to find a space that works for both iPhone 4 and iPhone 5 sizes... Also remember iPhone 6!

Drag the 1st `UIView`on the second while pressing CTRL and set a fixed "vertical spacing" constraint on all of them.

Do the same with 2nd to 3rd, 3rd to 4th, etc... They should keep the space in any screen size.

Comment: Actually, I do put UIButton in real project. For simple understanding I mention them as `UIView`. Any way I got the solution. Really appreciate your answer. Have a good day. :)

Answer (score 2):

Please check this URL: [evenly-space-multiple-views-within-a-container-view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25898949/4101371)

It will help you how to set view equally distant from each other without using spacer view.

Hope it helps in solving your problem.

Comment: Thanks. I got the solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure it will help you or not but I think you should use UITableView instead of using 4 different view.You can set height of sections in GROUPED UITableView for same space.

Comment: Thanks. That was a thought full idea. :)