# How to set space between two view using auto layout(in Aspect Ratio)

Tags: ios, autolayout, xib

I have two views in a view and i have a requirement to increase the distance between those views in aspect ratio to the main view. I am using auto layout.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you  set vertical spacing constraint  between them  ?

Comment: any image attachments?

Comment: yes i have set vertical spacing .but i want that space in aspect ratio.

Comment: maybe you can find something helpful here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13075415/evenly-space-multiple-views-within-a-container-view . I think you just need to set the bottom spacing and then adjust the multiplier according to your need.

Comment: add 1 more view(with clear color so its not seen or set hidden) ex : view3 between those two views Ex: View1, View2. set constraint with Two Views (View1, view2) .i. e. View3 top to view1 bottom (if it's above view2 & view 3)  & View3 Bottom to view2 bottom (if it's below view2 & view 1) . Now set equal  Hight Of view3 (new Separator View) to main view and set Multiplier as per requirement

Comment: @sourav, let me know if my answer helps your situation.

Comment: @UnisBarakat I tried that but it did not match my requirement .

Comment: @sourav, I've updated the answer. Hope it works out with this other method.  (This is the most I can do given that you didn't share any details in the project with us much. If you are willing to share files I can perhaps do this for you and send you a link.)

Comment: @sourav, you might want to check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13075415/evenly-space-multiple-views-within-a-container-view

Comment: @UnisBarakat thats i know .But that is not the question i have asked dear .

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve your problem is -

1. For your upper view give top space constraint with super view and other required constraint.
2. For your lower view give bottom space constraint with super view and other required constraints.

You don't really need to give vertical space because your views will be pinned with fixed space with top and bottom of super view, so if screen size will grow space between your views will automatically grow.

Important to note however: You must add the height constraint for both views and have either fixed width constraint or have Leading and trailing space constraints.

See ScreenShot

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion .But i have more than 2 views (20 views) .

Comment: Add Screenshot of your view, then it would be easier to solve issue.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have more than one view, I recommend doing the following assuming this is the result you are looking for:

[image]

**STEP 1 :**
select all your views

**Step 2 :**
go to Editor -> Embed In -> Stack View
(now it will group them together) I'm assuming that you set the width and height constraint for each of your views before doing this.

**Step 3 :**
once you have done that select the stack (not the individual views). but rather the entire stack (I would do this from the side menu) and set the top layout and the bottom layout.

**step 4 :**
Go here and make these settings for the stack as you have it selected

[image: final step]

and that should do it. 
Let me know if I should clarify anything.

UPDATE:

If you do not want equal spacing, you can still use the above method by playing around with different stacks, etc.. However, There is a method I've used in the past to get this, which is setting a multiplier instead of a number for say spacing between bottom layout and view. Here is an example that might help below:

[image]

you can play around with it to get your desired results.

Comment: @sourav best of luck

Comment: You have shown for equal spacing between views . Thats not my requirement dear .Let us assume the space between the view 1 and view 2 in iphone 5 is 40 and the same between 2 and 3 is 20 ,In iPhone 6 it should be 46.97 and 23.48 . and those view should also increase in aspect ratio .