# Autolayout with proportion

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

As we can set width,height,leading,trailing as proportional to modify according to screen size.

But how can we set vertical spacing between two controls as proportional as like above?

Please try to give solution instead of adding spaceview between controls.as it may be costlier.

Please Help
Lots of Thanks in Advance!

Comment: use spaceview between two controls ... check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13075415/evenly-space-multiple-views-within-a-container-view

Comment: @EICaptain do you have any other solution instead of adding spaceview between.as it may be costier.

Comment: no...I think this is the only solution I know...I don't know about stackview whether it works or not in this situation but if it works than its prior to iOS9 and above