# Auto layout space between elements relative to screen height

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, autolayout

Im new to auto layout, and im struggling to get my layout working properly. I want the vertical space between my elements to be relative to the height of the screen. Here is what my project looks like in the storyboard, as i have designed it (its a bit hard to see but there is a black text field above the segmented view).
[image]

This is what it looks like with my current autoLayout:
[image]

Notice how the space between the segmented control, label, text field and tableView dont increase as the screen gets bigger (or decrease as the screen gets smaller). What must i do in order to make this happen?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/25898949/1770246

Comment: Just use `Multiplier` to calculate the spaces based on the parent view's height