# How to vertically align in container two UIViews with variable heights

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, autolayout, constraints

I have an UICollectionViewCell that contains UIImageView and two UIViews with label in each (views are semi-transparent backgrounds):

[img]https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3EhQ.png

I want them to be aligned vertically in the cell. 
Top space of UIView#1 should be equal to bottom space of UIView#2.
The problem is that labels can contain long strings so they might span to 2 or 3 lines.
Examples of possible states:

1. Both labels have only 1 line
2. Both labels contain 2 lines
3. Top label contains 2 lines and bottom one contains 1 line
4. Top label contains 3 lines and bottom one contains 1 line
   etc.

When label grows its container (UIView#1 or UIView#2) should grow as well but two views as a group should still be vertically aligned:

[img]https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdIZW.png

[img]https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrGwk.png

I tried to embed them in another UIView but I can't set up valid constraints (I believe it is possible to solve this using auto layout only).

[img]https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hv1Na.png

Can somebody help me?

Comment: For this (and a lot of other) very reason there is the UIContainerView

Comment: Have a look at this [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25898949/2710486) answer