# IOS StoryBoard constraints; large space above bottom button

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, constraints

I'm new to Xcode and I'm using constraints. Why does the bottom button have so much space in between the 2nd bottom button? How can I fix this so the bottom button is moved up to be right under the 2nd most bottom button?

[image]

**What should I do here?**

[image]

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/25898949/3378413

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To move up the bottom button you could remove the bottom constraint to the superview.

You will also have to add a top constraint on this button, linking it to the one above.

Comment: Great! How would I add a constraint to make the button wider on a iPad screen?

Comment: Well that's difficult to answer in a comment. What you can do is read the Apple documentation on this matter here : [BuildingforMultipleScreenSizes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/BuildingforMultipleScreenSizes.html), or the cool RayWenderlich tutorial : [adaptive-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-getting-started](https://www.raywenderlich.com/113768/adaptive-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-getting-started)