# MVVMCross FluentLayout Equal Horizontal Spacing

Tags: ios, xamarin, mvvmcross, cirrious.fluentlayout

I am creating a TableCell using Cirrious.FluentLayout in MVVMCross to add constraints.
I've added four images to the ContentView and have had to manually space them out (Horizontally) by calculating the margin in the constructor

```
var gap = (ContentView.Frame.Width - (imagesize * 3) - 40) /6;
```

Then I use the calculated gap for the constraints

```
        _signalStrength.ToRightOf(_batteryLevel, gap),
        _childLockImage.ToRightOf(_signalStrength, gap),
```

Currently this will work fine as the app only runs in Portrait mode, but I am concerned that if we enable landscape mode then this will not work.

Is there a better way to have these images pace evenly across the table cell?

Comment: Are the images all the same size? Are you scaling them or rendering them in a particular resolution?

Comment: There are four images, three are `imagesize` and the other one has a width constraint of 40

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advise you to [use a UIStackView](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/introduction_to_ios9/uistackview/) in horizontal mode with equal spacing distribution. UIStackView was added in iOS 9 and really helps with these cases and eliminate the need for a huge amount of constraints.

In your case, with 4 views, laid out horizontally with equal spacing, the code would look something like:

```
var views = new UIView[] { view1, view2, view3, view4 };
var stackView = new UIStackView(views)
{
    Axis = UILayoutConstraintAxis.Horizontal,
    Distribution = UIStackViewDistribution.EqualSpacing
};
```

Then you simply constrain your stackView instead and subviews will layout inside of it.

Comment: I have ported TZStackView to Xamarin, if you care about iOS 7 and 8 and can be found on NuGet. The API is similar with some minor changes to enums used for Axis, Distribution etc. due to them not being present on those older versions.

Comment: When I add code like you gave I get an error when adding it with fluent constraints: NSInternalInconsistencyException Reason: Impossible to set up layout with view hierarchy unprepared for constraint. What am I missing?

Comment: Solution: make sure you  Add(stackView); before using it with constraints

Comment: @cfl like with any other view you want to add constraints for :)

Comment: :) true - confusion due to trying to add constraints on the individual views themselves, e.g. add textview onto view1 using it's own fluent constraint.

Answer (score 1):

UIStackView answer by @Cheesebaron is a very good way to go.

However, if you care about iOS 7-8 (UIStackView works on 9+), then here's what you can do:

```
view.AddConstraints(
    i1.WithSameCenterX(view).WithMultiplier(1 / 4f),
    i2.WithSameCenterX(view).WithMultiplier(3 / 4f),
    i3.WithSameCenterX(view).WithMultiplier(5 / 4f),
    v4.WithSameCenterX(view).WithMultiplier(7 / 4f)
);
```

i1-i3 are images of same size and v4 is some other view of different size. No manual calculation required.

Works in portrait mode:
[image: portrait]

and landscape:

[image: landscape]

The idea is explained in this brilliant answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30249550/883738

If your views will be of different size, this might be not exactly what you want:

[image: not exactly what you need]

Comment: You can use TZStackView on iOS versions prior to 9. Full disclaimer, I made a port for Xamarin.iOS which is on NuGet.