# Is there a better way to evenly distribute subviews in a UIview with unknown size?

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I want to horizontally place 4 subviews in a screen-width view, and I want the subviews to be evenly distributed (with equal horizontal spacing).

One way to do it is to use hidden placer-views, and add equal-width constraints: [Evenly space multiple views within a container view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13075415/evenly-space-multiple-views-within-a-container-view)

This answer is written in 13, so I am wondering if there is a more elegant solution to the problem today, without introducing hidden views.

1. I know about UIStackView, but it's in iOS 9.0, and I need to support at least iOS 8.0.
2. Programmatically adding spacing constraints obviously works. But I prefer using the storyboard to solve this.

Comment: have you tried the top voted but not accepted answer to that question https://stackoverflow.com/a/25898949/2442804 ?

Comment: Yes, that works. That answer is ranked so low...